# Scrollviews within horizontal scrollview disables horizontal scroll - SwiftUI

Tags: macos, swiftui, scrollview

I am creating a set of lists in a horizontal scrollview for a MacOS App. Basically the lists would appear side by side.

```
   var body: some View {

    ScrollView (.horizontal, showsIndicators: true){
           ForEach(self.dates, id: \.self) { day in
                  ScrollView {
                       Text("\day.date")
                       Text("Other content")
           }
       }
    }
}
```

The individual (vertical) scrollviews make it not possible for the app to register horizontal scrolling. When having the pointer on the individual lists, the only option is vertical scrolling. When putting the pointer in between the lists (outside - but within the horizontal scrollview) the horizontal scrolling works.

Any ideas on how to enable horizontal scrolling while hovering over a vertical scrollview?

Other option would be to make horizontal scrollbar indicator visible **at all times**, but currently it hides itself when not moved. Any ideas on how to achieve that?

Comment: Just a question, do you want both ScrollViews to scroll horizontally and vertically?

Comment: I'm dealing with the same issue.
I have Horizontal ScrollView that contains multiple Lists, and I can't scroll horizontally when the mouse is positioned on any of the lists (only vertically).

Comment: @VincentBee Did you find a fix?